# Linear system question

Tags: linear, system

I have been struggling with this linear system's question. [[image: linear system question]][image: solution 1][image: solution 3]
I have arrived at a solution, but i do not think my solution makes sense.

Comment: \$y(0) = -2+6 = x_1(0) - x_2(0)\$. Your solution \$x_1(0)=0\ ,\ x_2(0)=0\$ doesn't satisfy the above relation.

Comment: yeah, thats why i said i believe there is something wrong with mine...

Comment: You first line \$X(s) = (sI-A)^{-1}BU(s)\$ doesn't account for the initial condition. That equation assumes zero initial condition. That is why you ended up with zero as result (probably).

Comment: You need to add a term like \$X_0(s)\$ to \$BU(s)\$ and then pre multiply it with \$sI-A\$ inverse. (I think)

Comment: so how would that happen, I haven't seen that in classes? @AJN

Comment: Remember; \$L(dX/dt) = sX - X(0)\$. Only then will the initial condition be accounted for, IMO.

Comment: but X(0) =0 in that case no ?

Comment: im really lost, to be honest

Comment: I believe I know how to solve it,
y(t)=C*e^At*x(0) ∫ eA(t-k)Bu(k)dk +Du(t)
and we solve for x(0)